# Tuleap ldap query no such object odd query text

Tags: ldap, tuleap

I've integrated Tuleap ldap, and successfully connected with user/password, but when I try to search a user (during log-in), I get a line in tuleap log:

[warning] LDAP search error:  sAMAccountName=[what i type in tuleap login screen] [string from ldap server field] ***ERROR:No such object ***ERROR no:32

It looks like front login page forwards my dcserver name to the ldap query filter?
I did try to do the ldapsearch directly from shell and it works flawlesly.

It is really odd, if I add more dc servers separated by coma, then I get all of them in the log

[warning] LDAP search error:  sAMAccountName=[what i type in tuleap login screen] dc1,dc2,dc3 ***ERROR:No such object ***ERROR no:32

Why does it forward my dc name to the ldap query?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "It looks like front login page forwards my dcserver name to the ldap query filter?". + it would be convenient to share your ldap config (be careful with sensitive data!)

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain (will upload config tomorrow).

My ldap server is, for example dc1,dc2,dc3
I type user1 in login screen of tuleap

The log in codendi log says:
[warning] LDAP search error: sAMAccountName=user1 dc1,dc2,dc3 ***ERROR:No such object ***ERROR no:32

Of course there is no samacount name 'user1 dc1,dc2,dc3' in the dc1, so I get an error. I've tried ldapsearch directly searching for user1 and it works